# Spying with mockito on Akka actor

Tags: akka, mockito, scalatest

I would like to spy on my actor instance, but it cannot be simply created with new keyword. I figured out following solution:

```
  val testActorSpy = spy(TestActorRef(new TestActor).underlyingActor)
  val testActorRef = TestActorRef(testActorSpy )
```

but this way I create one unnecessary actor. Is there any cleaner solution?

Answer (score 1):

So my understanding of the Akka Actor system is that you should be doing this through properties then right?

Thus create the actor through Props and when under testing just return a spy to the actor.

thus this should give you a result:

```
val testActorRef = TestActorRef(spy(new TestActor))
val testActorSpy = testActorRef.underlyingActor
```

Be aware that the underlyingActor gets destroyed when the actor is restarted. so mocking this might not be the best option.

If using the actor directly rather going through the system you might be able to test things as well and bypassing the threaded underlying system.

See [this](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/testing.html) (code paste below for java).

```
static class MyActor extends UntypedActor {
  public void onReceive(Object o) throws Exception {
    if (o.equals("say42")) {
      getSender().tell(42, getSelf());
    } else if (o instanceof Exception) {
      throw (Exception) o;
    }
  }
  public boolean testMe() { return true; }
}

@Test
public void demonstrateTestActorRef() {
  final Props props = Props.create(MyActor.class);
  final TestActorRef<MyActor> ref = TestActorRef.create(system, props, "testA");
  final MyActor actor = ref.underlyingActor();
  assertTrue(actor.testMe());
}
```

Comment: The only public method of an actor should be the `onReceive`. Otherwise, the immutability is at risk. In this case, if `testMe` method modifies the actor's state, that principle is violated. `testMe`should be private. To access private methods on JUnit tests with Spring, use the `ReflectionTestUtils`.

Comment: Make it package private then. There is tons of ways to modify visibility.  Everybody who works on our code base is aware that mutable shared state is bad. And ActorRef doesn't expose public functions. So it has not been a problem. Our race conditions have come from closing over private state ..

Comment: You are right. The public methods inside an actor aren't exposed. I just have a feeling like it is a code smell. But from the functional perspective, you are right.

Anyways, in case someone else wants to keep their methods private, remember they can be called with `ReflectionTestUtils`